# How to unwrap a mongodb nested document with unknown field names

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have some data coming from an IoT device and i am storing that in the mongodb using the following structure:

```
{
data:{
<timeStamp1>:<energyValue1>,
<timeStamp2>:<energyValue2>,
<timeStamp3>:<energyValue3>,...
}
}
```

For example:

```
{
"data":{
"1648310504":51,
"1648310404":25,
"1648310304":63

}

}
```

Is there a way to unwrap this document into multiple documents in the aggregation pipeline so that the output in that stage will look something like this

Document 1.
{
"timestamp":1648310504,
"data":51
}

Document 2.
{
"timestamp":1648310404,
"data":25
}

Document 3.
{
"timestamp":1648310304,
"data":63
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 "$addFields": {
    "data": {
      "$objectToArray": "$data"
    }
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$data"
},
{
  $project: {
    timestamp: "$data.k",
    data: "$data.v",
    _id: 0
   }
  }
])
```

Explained:

1. Convert the object data to array with elements key->k , value->v
2. Unwind the array data so it disasemble to individual documents.
3. Project the data sub-fileds as expected to timestamp & data.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cVY2rTYJDDt)